# Pop OS with a deduplication filesystem

Tags: filesystems, pop-os, bootable, deduplication, refs

I'm moving a friend development machine to Linux (PopOS), permanently. Don't worry guys, he dualbooted and he's ready for the tux.

The problem is his drive. It's a 256GB SSD, and he is moving from a rusty 512GB HDD almost full of projects, where a most of the space used is from vendor shared libraries (npm hell, composer, to name a few).

Since package managers would download a library, and then copy it over the project, I think it would be convenient for a filesystem that deals with deduplication.

I'm trying to check if there is a filesystem to deduplicate files on Linux, as [Microsoft "Dev Drive"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-drive/) that can work (hopefully, but not required) as a boot drive too.

Comment: The .deb file downloaded by `apt` may contain compressed tar's for the control and data sections of the archive. If so, a de-dup will not help you any as the data blocks for the compressed and uncompressed files will not match.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear that de-duplication will actually save you a whole lot. Often a popular library will get pulled in through transitive dependencies in distinct versions, which will not allow for de-dup.

In any event, the file system  you’re looking for is [ZFS](https://github.com/truenas/documentation/blob/master/content/References/ZFSDeduplication.md).